# How to scroll down multiple lines of ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

`ScrollViewer.LineDown()`  is used to scroll down one line in `ScrollViewer`.
Is there a way to scroll down multiple lines by one shot.

Something like
`ScrollViewer.LinesDown(5)`

Answer (score 2):

You could implement an extension method to do it, as there is no standard way to do it. Which would be pretty useful.

```
public static void LinesDown(this ScrollViewer scroll, int lines)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        scroll.LineDown();
}
```

Then you can call it like you wanted to

```
ScrollViewer.LinesDown(5);
```